# Where to download Silverlight Developer Runtime nowadays?

Tags: silverlight

After the retirement of Silverlight, I am finding a hard time finding the Silverlight Developer Runtime for download.

I need to set up a dev environment to compile a Silverlight 5 app with VS 2015.

Any ideas where I can get it?

Comment: It should be included in the VS2015 ISO download that one can get from https://my.visualstudio.com/.
Otherwise, it is still included in Expression Blend 4, which is also available from https://my.visualstudio.com/.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I managed to find it just by looking at the VS2015 ISO. I had to first uninstall the current Silverlight runtime I had installed. I guess it was newer than the one on the ISO file. Then I reinstalled the SDK and DRT and it the project loaded just fine!